# Operations on Two Streams of Data - Design Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have seen this algorithm question or variants of it several times but have not found or been able to determine an optimal solution to the problem. The question is:

> You are given two queues where each queue contains {timestamp, price}
>   pair. You have to print "price 1, price 2" pair for all those
>   timestamps where abs(ts1-ts2) <= 1 second where ts1 and price1 are
>   from the first queue and ts2 and price2 are from the second queue.

How would you design a system to handle these requirements?

Then a followup on this questions: what if one of the queues is slower than the other (data is delayed). How would you handle this?

Comment: Are the queues sorted by time stamp?

Comment: @TomerGodinger yes

Comment: You may want to leave comments indicating the problem with answers already posted if they are not satisfactory.

Comment: I would be interested in answering this question, except that 1) I find myself having to guess about why you didn't like the earlier answers.  I'm guessing that you want a real time solution and that multiple entries from queue 1 can pair against a single entry in queue 2 and vice versa, for example.  2) You didn't say what 'optimal' means to you.  Do you want pairs output as soon as possible, for example.  3) I wouldn't be linking to an "official source".  If you want search results you can get those yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a similar fashion to the merging algorithm from merge sort, only doubled.

I'm going to describe an algorithm in which I choose queue #1 to be my "main queue." This will only provide a partial solution; I'll explain how to complete it afterwards.

At any time you keep one entry from each queue in memory. Whenever the two entries you have uphold your condition of being less than one second apart, print out their prices. Whether or not you did, you discard the one with the lower time stamp and get the next one. If at any point the time stamp from queue #1 is lower than that from queue #2, discard entries from queue #1 until that is no longer the case. If they both have the same time stamp, print it out and advance the one from queue #1. Repeat until done.

This will print out all the pairs of "`price1`, `price2`" whose corresponding `ts1` and `ts2` uphold that `0 <= ts1 - ts2 <= 1`.

Now, for the other half, do the same only this time choose queue #2 as your "main queue" (i.e. do everything I just said with the numbers 1 and 2 reversed) - except don't print out pairs with equal time stamps, since you've already printed those in the first part.

This will print out all the pairs of "`price1`, `price2`" whose corresponding `ts1` and `ts2` uphold that `0 < ts2 - ts1 <= 1`, which is like saying `0 > ts1 - ts2 >= -1`.

Together you get the printout for all the cases in which `-1 <= ts1 - ts2 <= 1`, i.e. in which `abs(ts1 - ts2) <= 1`.

Comment: Queues are generally assumed to have little more than an "enqueue" and a "dequeue" method. As such, this solution will require creating copies of the queues, which is far from ideal. However, this can be modified to keep the last second's elements in memory, requiring only a single pass.

Comment: You could make two new queues and each time you dequeue queue #1, put it in both of them. Same for queue #2. Then you work with those queues and make the transfer whenever one of them is empty.

Answer (score 0):

1. Additionally to the queues use two hashmaps (each exclusive for one queue)
2. As soon as a new item arrives strip the seconds out and use this as the key of the corresponding hashmap.
3. Using the very same key, retrieve all the items in the other hashmap.
4. One by one compare if the actual retrieved items are 1 second away of the item in bullet 2.

Note that this will fail to detect items with a difference in minutes: 10:00:59 and 10:01:00 will not be detected.

To solve this:

- for items like XX:XX:59 you will need to hit the hashmap twice using keys XX:XX and XX:XX+1.
- for items like XX:XX:00 you will need to hit the hashmap twice using keys XX:XX and XX:XX-1.

Note: do a date addition (not a mathematical one) since it will automatically deal with things like 01:59:59 + 1 = 02:00:00 or Monday 1 23:59:59 becoming Tuesday 2 00:00:00.

BTW, this algorithm also deals with the delay issue.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the queues does not matter at all if the algorithm is based on the comparison of timestamps alone. If one queue is empty and you cannot proceed just check periodically until you can continue.

You can solve this by managing a list for one of the queues. In the algorithm below the first was chosen, therefore it is called l1. It works like a sliding window.

1. Dequeue the 2nd queue: d2.
2. While the timestamp of the head of l1 is smaller than the one of d2 and the difference is greater than 1: remove the head from l1.
3. Go through the list and print all the pairs l1[i].price, d2.price as long as the difference of the timestamps is smalller than 1. If you don't reach the end of the list, continue with step 1.
4. Get the next element from the first queue and add it to the list. If the difference between the timestamps is smaller than 1 print the prices and repeat, if not continue with step 1.

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution, you need following services.

1. Design a service to read the message from Queue1 and push the data to DB
2. Design another service to read the message from Queue2 and push the data to same DB.
3. Design another service to read the data from DB and print the result as per the frequency of result needed.

**Edit**
 above specified system is designed ,keepin below point in mind

**Scalablity**  - if load for system increases number of services can be scale up

**Slowness** as already mention one queu is slow then other , chances are ,first queue recieving more message then second ,hence not able to produce desired out put.

**Otput Frequencey** in future if requirement changes and instead of 1 sec difference we want to show 1 hour diffference ,then it is also very much possible.

Comment: There is a catch to this, with your solution I can have a condition where abs(t1-t2) <= 1 gets satisfied from two timestamps of the same queue, I need a way to distinguish them.

Comment: Actually, you could add a `source` column so you could distinguish between the two sources, but honestly, using a database for this seems way overkill to me.

Comment: for very small requirement ,the above statements are  correct ,now think of a large system where number of message keep increasing from both the queue ,will the system still perform ,i doubt.

Answer (score -1):

Get the first element from both queues.

Compare the timestamps. If within one second, output the pair.

From the queue that gave the earlier timestamp, get the next element.

Repeat.

EDIT:

After @maraca's comment, I had to rethink my algorithm. And yes, if on both queues there are multiple events within a second, it will not produce all combinations.